# How can I designate tag of struct in C from a user?

Tags: c, input, struct, tags, clang

I tried to designate tag(structure tag name) of struct from user's input during execution.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

struct todo
{
    int when;     
};


int main(void)
{
    char t1[10];
    printf("Title :");
    scanf("%s", &t1);

    struct todo t1;
    printf("Time: ");
    scanf("%d", &t1.when);     // "&t1" is the problem, but I can't fix this. 
    printf("%d", t1.when);     // "t1" also the problem

    return 0;
}
```

Is there any way to fix my code or designate tag name?

I'm using visual studio 2017, windows 10

Comment: `char t1[10]` defines `t1` to be an array of ten `char`, and `struct todo t1` defines `t1` to be a structure of type `struct todo`. You cannot reuse a name within the same scope. Is the compiler giving you an error message on the `struct todo t1;` line? If so, just use a different name, like `t2`. (You can reuse names in different scopes, such as having a `foo` outside a function and a different `foo` inside a function. You can even do this with nested blocks [statements inside `{ … }`] inside a function. But it should be done judiciously. For this case, just use different names.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks for your comment! There is no error message on the `struct todo t1`.  Designating struct name during execution (run) by scanf is what I meant. How can I do this..?

Comment: The code in the question does not match the compiler behavior you report. A typical compiler will issue a warning for the first `scanf` line because `&t1` is the address of an array, but `%s` requires the address of a `char`, and will issue an error for the `struct todo t1;` line because `t1` is already defined. Then it will issue further warnings or errors for the `scanf` and `printf` lines. First, ensure the text in the question is **exactly** what you are compiling. Then copy and paste the output from the compiler into the question (use `<pre>` and `</pre>` to mark it as preformatted text).